# Using output value of column from function for another column in SQL*Loader

Tags: function, oracle11g, sql-loader

This question with title `Using output value of column from function for another column in SQL*Loader`is now moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90122/using-output-value-of-column-from-function-for-another-column-in-sqlloader